# how to prevent proguard break phonegap app

Tags: cordova, proguard, obfuscation, cordova-plugin-proguard

Trying to obfuscate my phonegap application
after launching i am getting

367 D/CordovaLog(30913): file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js: Line 913 : Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'exec'

I think i tried all options mentioned in the web, here is my proguard-project.txt

```
-keep public class * extends com.phonegap.api.Plugin 
-keep public class org.apache.cordova.** 
-keep class org.apache.cordova.** { *; }
-keep public class * extends org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin
-keep public class * extends org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin
-keep public class * extends com.phonegap.api.Plugin
-keep public class * extends org.apache.cordova.api.Plugin
-keep public class org.apache.cordova.DroidGap
-keep public class org.apache.cordova.**
-keep public class org.apache.**
-keep public class com.kazem.**
-keep public class nl.**
-dontwarn android.webkit.*
-dontwarn org.apache.**
-dontwarn  android.support.v7.widget.**
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-keepdirectories
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepclassmembers class * {
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
}
```

Comment: What version of phonegap you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1).Uncomment the following line in the project.properties file

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

2).Inside AndroidSDk/tools/proguard/proguard-project.txt Add bellow lines ,Because  our project uses WebView with JS  So,we have to  specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface class:

```
-keep public class * extends org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin
-keep public class * extends com.phonegap.api.Plugin 
-keep class org.apache.cordova.** { *; }
-dontwarn android.webkit.*
```

3).Build Android project.
4).Copy “proguard-project.txt “ file from  “AndroidSDk/tools/proguard/proguard-project.txt” to android folder.
5).Export signed package :Right click on project > android tools > Export signed application package

Answer (score 1):

I used:

```
-keep public class * extends org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin
-keep public class * extends com.phonegap.api.Plugin 
-keep class org.apache.cordova.** { *; }
-dontwarn android.webkit.*
```